# Deleting multiple rows with checboxes

Tags: angular

I am able to delete a single row by checking a box. When i try to select multiple boxes, the current checked box is the only row deleted leaving the previously selected check box.   Below is my code . please help

```java
//Service

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "RxJS/Rx";
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class FoodService {    

    constructor(private http:Http) {

    }

    RemoveFood(id) {
        return this.http.delete('http://example.com ' + id)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
    }
}
```

//Food Module

```java
export class Food (
    public count: number;
    public price: number;
    public location: string;
    public type: string;
    public selected: string;    
) { }
```

//Food table

```java
<tr *ngFor="let food of Food">

    <td><input #{{food.count}} [(ngModel)]="food.selected" type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(food)"></td>
    <td>{{food.count}}</td>
    <td>{{food.price}}</td>
    <td>{{food.location}}</td>
    <td>{{food.type}}</td>

</tr>
```

//Food Component

```java
export class FoodComponent {

    Food : Food[] = [];

    constructor(private foodService: FoodService) { }

    selectedFood : Food;

    deleteFoodSelected() {
        this.foodService.RemoveFood(this.selectedFood.id)
        .subscribe(data => { console.log(data) })    
    }

    //checkbox function
    checkbox(food) {
        food.selected = (food.selected) ? true: false;
        this.selectedFood = food;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you'll need to loop through your foods, find all the ones which are selected, and call RemoveFood() for each of their ID.

Comment: @JBNizet How do you mean? If i get this right, I tried to loop with the selected string in the food module

Comment: The only loop you posted is the ngFor displaying all the foods.

Comment: @JBNizet  i am stuck. could you help me

Comment: Why don't you at least try something? I already told you that you need to loop through the foods, find the ones which are selected, and call RemoveFoo() with their ID. This is simple stuff. You should know how to loop in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace Your code in food table,

```
<td><input #{{food.count}} [(ngModel)]="food.selected" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>{{food.count}}</td>
  <td>{{food.price}}</td>
  <td>{{food.location}}</td>
  <td>{{food.type}}</td>
</tr>
<button (click)="deleteFoodSelected()">DeleteSelectedFood</button>
```

In Food Module,

```
    export class Food (
        public Id: number;
        public count: number;
        public price: number;
        public location: string;
        pubic  type: string;
        public selected: string;

    ){}
```

In food component,

```
 selectedFood : Food[];

     deleteFoodSelected(){
        this.selectedFood= this.Food.filter(_ => _.selected);
            for (var food in this.selectedFood) {
           this.foodService.RemoveFood(this.selectedFood[food].Id)
             .subscribe(data =>{
              console.log(data)
             }   
             )    
          }
}
```

// In service.ts

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "RxJS/Rx";
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

 export class FoodService {


  constructor(private http:Http) {


  }
  RemoveFood(id) {
    return this.http.delete('http://example.com ' + id)
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
  }   
}
```